# QCommandLineOption: count repeated argument?

Tags: qt, qt5, command-line-arguments

I would like to use `-v` flag to indicate verbosity, and if repeated more times, increase verbosity accordingly, similar to e.g. the openssh client. Is this possible with `QCommandLineParser` & `QCommandLineOption`? I looked into the API docs and google around and did not find any hint. Thanks!

Comment: Never used ssh? `man openssh` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. `optionNames()` for example will return all instances of an option found on the CLI. So will `values()`.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QCommandLineParser clp;
  clp.addOptions({ {QStringLiteral("v"), QStringLiteral("Verbose leval.")} });
  clp.process(a);
  qDebug() << clp.optionNames().count("v") << clp.optionNames();
  return 0;
}
```

```
$  ./app -v -v -v
-> 3 ("v", "v", "v")
```